# index inside for loop in python 3.1

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, indexing

I can't understand a behavior .index method inside for loop
(Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 20:30:21) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)

```
L = [e for e in range(11)]
print(L)
for e in L[:]:
    print(e, L.index(e))
    L[L.index(e)] *= e
print(L)
```

output:

```
>>> 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 2
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 3
10 10
[0, 1, 16, 81, 4, 25, 36, 49, 64, 9, 100]
>>>
```

I expected the final list [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you hit `4`, your list is `[0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, having replaced the first 3 elements. `.index()` finds the **first** occurence of `4`, at index 2, not 5, as you appear to be expecting. The same goes for `9`; you already replaced `3` with `9` earlier in the loop and `L.index(9)` returns `3` instead of `10`.

Don't use `list.index()` on a changing list; use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
L = [e for e in range(11)]
print(L)
for i, e in enumerate(L[:]):
    print(e, i)
    L[i] *= e
print(L)
```

which then results in:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

You can replace `[e for e in range(11)]` with a simple `list(range(11))`. And you can replace your whole script with:

```
[e * e for e in range(11)]
```

Comment: Sure, accepted. This procedure also not secret for me anymore ))